# How and when did trespass become a crime, or not a crime?

Tags: united-states, england-and-wales, trespass, any-jurisdiction

principally interested in the us and in England, but what are the origins of trespass being treated as not a crime in England, and conversely as a crime in the U.S.? As with terminology for civil burdens of truth? How did they diverge or who diverged from whom?

Answer (score 2):

There hasn't really been any such divergence. The elements may vary, but trespass can be prosecuted both civilly and criminally in both jurisdictions.

Comment: No in England only aggravated trespass can be a criminal offence

Comment: I'd humbly suggest that aggravated trespass is a trespass.

Comment: @Seekinganswers Simple trespass may not be criminal in the US either. For example, it's merely an [infraction in Connecticut](https://casetext.com/statute/general-statutes-of-connecticut/title-53a-penal-code/chapter-952-penal-code-offenses/part-viii-burglary-criminal-trespass-arson-criminal-mischief-and-related-offenses/section-53a-110a-simple-trespass-infraction).